# Matplotlib, Inkscape, TeXStudio workflow SVG figures

Tags: python, svg, inkscape, matplotlib, matplotlib2tikz

When I create an SVG figure in matplotlib

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

new_rc_params = {'text.usetex': False,
"svg.fonttype": 'none'
}
matplotlib.rcParams.update(new_rc_params)

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel(r'x \$\rightarrow\$')
plt.ylabel(r'y \$\rightarrow\$')
plt.savefig('./figures/figure.svg', format='svg')
```

and then run `txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]` in TeXstudio, Inkscape (version 1.0.2) automatically generates a .pdf and a .pdf_tex file of the figure. I then want to integrate the figure in LaTeX:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\svgsetup{inkscapeexe=inkscape, inkscapearea=drawing, inkscapeversion=1}
\svgpath{{figures/}}

\begin{document}
This is a test document
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includesvg[width=1\textwidth]{figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Compiling that LaTeX file leads to the following error message:
`Package inputenc Error: Unicode character − (U+2212)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.`

The error is due to the following lines in the .pdf_tex file:

```latex
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}−1.00\end{tabular}}
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}−0.75\end{tabular}}
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}−0.50\end{tabular}}
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}−0.25\end{tabular}}
```

Those lines appear in order to draw the axis ticks.

What am I missing? Is Inkscape generating "faulty" .pdf_tex files? Is there a clean way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which indeed helped me a lot. However, I was busy and could not check the answers thoroughly up until now. That's why I didn't vote earlier. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: No problem at all! Happy to be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `matplotlib`  is using the Unicode "MINUS SIGN" to represent the minus in negative numbers instead of the ASCII hyphen. The other answers explain how to adapt LaTeX to accept it; another option is to tell `matplotlib` to not do it, by setting it to use the ASCII symbol instead.

In my opinion, it is better to tackle the problem at the origin and directly avoiding it. You have more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201310/use-of-hyphen-or-minus-sign-in-matplotlib-versus-compatibility-with-latex.

Basically, if I run your Python code, in the `svg` file I have this:

[image]

but if I add:

```python
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus']=False
```

the `svg` file will have negative labels with a "real" minus (for whatever value of real you mean here --- I understand it is debatable):

[image]

and so you shouldn't have any problem with the LaTeX side (can't check because I do not have your setup...)

Answer (score 2):

You could either switch to LuaTeX instead of pdfTeX or just declare a reasonable substitution for the missing character like `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ensuremath{-}}`, `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\textminus}` or `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ifmmode-\else--\fi}`. This should work:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{svg}
\svgsetup{inkscapeexe=inkscape, inkscapearea=drawing, inkscapeversion=1}
\svgpath{{figures/}}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ensuremath{-}}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\textminus}

\begin{document}
This is a test document
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includesvg[width=1\textwidth]{figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This produces the expected outcome, thanks! Is there any implicit behaviour along with ```\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ensuremath{-}}``` that I should be aware of in a larger document such as a thesis?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. However, if problems arise, you can simply change the definition to `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\textminus}`. Alternatively, `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ifmmode-\else--\fi}` would be a proper definition. At least package `utf8add` does that. I will adapt my answer. Please mark it as accepted if you are fine with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The errors at those lines are because you're not using the ASCII hyphen as minus sign, instead a unicode variant of it. You could try adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your preamble, and LaTeX might be able to recognize it. If it does, then it's still the question whether Computer Modern provides that character.

I would just swap those minus signs for the ASCII minus sign (the one on your keyboard). Next, if you're not editing the SVG files, I suggest you have matplotlib output a PDF instead

```
plt.savefig('./figures/figure.pdf')
```

and include in the preamble `\usepackage{graphicx}`. You then don't need the SVG conversions, which makes your document more robust. To include the PDF you use the native

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure}
```

or

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure.pdf}
```

instead.

Comment: You probably meant `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of `\usepackage[utf8]{encoding}` which is the default input encoding since `2018-04-01` I think. But `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` would be possible.

Comment: @mrpiggi Indeed. Thanks for noticing!