# How to write "-" in latex?

Tags: unicode

I have tried $-$ but it does not seem to work on Overleaf. I also tried finding the syntax for `-` but could not. Would really appreciate if someone could please help me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Well, type `-`.

Comment: @egreg Next question: How do you type “P” in LaTeX? `;-)`

Comment: make sure that you type `-` (a keyboard ASCII hyphen-minus) if you copy from Word or similar you might get `−` a Unicode minus sign, that doesn't work by default in pdflatex.

Comment: Similar to this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597807/matplotlib-inkscape-texstudio-workflow-svg-figures. `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ensuremath{-}}` (Hoping that the source is not using U+2212 as an en-dash)

Comment: I see that \texthyphen is no longer supported, but  \textendash, \textemdash and \textminus are.

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
text mode: -

math mode: $-$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If, like Rmano said, you want a minus in the text mode, you can use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
text mode: −

math mode: $-$
\end{document}
```

and compile the file using lualatex.

[image]

Comment: Those are `-` (ASCII hyphen), not `−` (Unicode minus sign) as the author is asking for. Try to copy and paste it into your document...

Comment: Now it's better. Or you can add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ensuremath{-}}` in the preamble and compile with `pdflatex`...

Comment: Thank you for all the help! Yesterday whenever I was using "-" in overleaf between numbers I was getting error. But I tried using "-" between numbers today and it works fine. I still don't know why it was acting up.